# Documentation: Created new topic, one example disappeared

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-proposals

On C++ Language I created a topic called Resource Management. I added an introduction and two examples, and submitted it for review. When I clicked on my proposal to check on it it only showed one of the two examples. This is strange given that the "what has changed" text showed "topic created, added 2 examples, added introduction". I just wanted to report this (apparent) bug.

Answer (score -1):

My proposal was approved, and when I looked at it, the second example was there. Apparently this is only a problem when looking at proposals, or (perhaps more likely) I missed something like a "next" button.